# How to make sure I click the correct rect after the canvas has been zoomed and translated?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

### The context

I'm creating a very simple game with html canvas (inside a next.js app). In this canvas I draw a few rectangles with some gap in between. If you know coloring pixels the game I bascially recreating this.
This is what it looks like so far:

[image]

I also implemented a zoom feature and drag feature. The logic for it I found on google.
But here is how the update function looks like:

```
update = (ctx) => {
    this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

    ctx.translate(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2);
    ctx.scale(this.cameraZoom, this.cameraZoom);
    ctx.translate(
      -window.innerWidth / 2 + this.cameraOffset.x,
      -window.innerHeight / 2 + this.cameraOffset.y
    );
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, window.width, window.height);
    this.drawTiles(ctx);
  };
```

`this.cameraZoom` just changes on mousewheel and the `this.cameraOffset` changes on mousemove and starts with `cameraOffset = { x: window.innerWidth / 2, y: window.innerHeight / 2 };` . This works fine, I can zoom in and drag the canvas around.
The problem I have is when I click the squares - the wrong rectangles get filled after dragging

### The Problem

Before the zoom and drag feature I implemented a logic, so I can click on the canvas and the correct rectangle will be filled with a color. That works fine. Then I implemented zooming, and I adjusted that logic until I made it work. But now I have to readjust it further because after dragging the "coordinates" aren't correct anymore, but I can't figure out a correct formula. Here is what I have so far (this function sits on every `tile` or `rect` I draw:

```
setPaintingColor = (game) => {
   
    const minX = (this.x - game.gap) * game.cameraZoom;
    const maxX = (this.x + this.width - game.gap) * game.cameraZoom;

    const minY = (this.y - game.gap) * game.cameraZoom;
    const maxY = (this.y + this.height - game.gap) * game.cameraZoom;

    if (!game.mouse.down) {
      return;
    }

    if (
      game.mouse.x >= minX &&
      game.mouse.x <= maxX &&
      game.mouse.y >= minY &&
      game.mouse.y <= maxY
    ) {
      this.color = "yellow";
    }
  };
```

So this sets the fill color of the rect and then the game update loop constantly calls draw of each rect (which fills the rect with the set color `this.color`.

### The question

So now I want to find out a logic that works after dragging and zooming. When I drag the canvas and then try to click rects, nothing get painted.

I played around with the `this.cameraOffset.x + y` values adding it, subtracting it etc, the closest I got was, when i clicked a tile, the tile to the left got painted but it wasn't logical to me at all.

So what I also tried is I calculate the distance I have moved after dragging (I set `this.dragStart` and `this.dragEnd` at the game object. Then adding it to the `setPaintingColor` function like that:

```
const distanceMovedX = game.dragStart.x - game.dragEnd.x;
    const distanceMovedY = game.dragStart.y - game.dragEnd.y;
    const minX = (this.x - game.gap + distanceMovedX) * game.cameraZoom;
    const maxX =
      (this.x + this.width - game.gap + distanceMovedX) * game.cameraZoom;

    const minY = (this.y - game.gap + distanceMovedY) * game.cameraZoom;
    const maxY =
      (this.y + this.height - game.gap + distanceMovedY) * game.cameraZoom;
```

Now when I drag and then click rects, about 6 - 8 tiles to the right where i clicked the rects get painted.

**Does anybody know which logic I need to make it work again?**

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

The `game` object has a `translateX` and `translateY` property. That is calculated after the canvas have been moved and also some other calculation with screen width etc.

This is the logic that works now:

```
setPaintingColor = (game) => {
    if (game.wantsToDrag) {
      return;
    }

    const minX = (this.x - game.gap + game.translateX) * game.cameraZoom;
    const maxX =
      (this.x + this.width - game.gap + game.translateX) * game.cameraZoom;

    const minY = (this.y - game.gap + game.translateY) * game.cameraZoom;
    const maxY =
      (this.y + this.height - game.gap + game.translateY) * game.cameraZoom;

    if (!game.mouse.down) {
      return;
    }

    if (
      game.mouse.x >= minX &&
      game.mouse.x <= maxX &&
      game.mouse.y >= minY &&
      game.mouse.y <= maxY
    ) {
      this.color = "yellow";
    }
  };
}
```

So basically I added `game.translateX` and `game.translateY` to the calculation and then multiplying it with the camera zoom.

Now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To get from a pixel to a context coordinate, you can use `getTransform` like so:

```js
const x = e.clientX - cvs.offsetLeft;
const y = e.clientY - cvs.offsetTop;
const { x: xt, y: yt } = ctx
  .getTransform()
  .invertSelf()
  .transformPoint({ x, y })
```

Here's a working snippet:

```js
const cvs = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
const zoomSlider = document.querySelector("[data-slide=zoom]");
const xSlider = document.querySelector("[data-slide=panx]");
const ySlider = document.querySelector("[data-slide=pany]");

const S = 8;
const grid = Array.from({ length: 256 / S }, () => Array(256 / S).fill(0));
const drawGrid = () => {
  grid.forEach((row, r) => {
    row.forEach((cell, c) => {
      ctx.fillStyle = cell ? "blue": "white";
      ctx.fillRect(
        c * 8 + 1,
        r * 8 + 1,
        S - 2,
        S - 2
      );
    });
  });
}

const setTransform = () => {
  const dx = xSlider.valueAsNumber;
  const dy = ySlider.valueAsNumber;
  const zoom = zoomSlider.valueAsNumber;
  ctx.translate(dx, dy);
  ctx.scale(zoom, zoom);
}

const update = () => {
  ctx.resetTransform();
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height);
  setTransform();
  drawGrid();
}

// Interactivity
[zoomSlider, xSlider, ySlider].forEach(el => el.addEventListener("input", update));
cvs.addEventListener("click", e => {
  const x = e.clientX - cvs.offsetLeft;
  const y = e.clientY - cvs.offsetTop;
  const { x: xt, y: yt } = ctx
    .getTransform()
    .invertSelf()
    .transformPoint({ x, y })

  // Color the right cell
  const cx = Math.floor(xt / S);
  const cy = Math.floor(yt / S);
  grid[cy][cx] = 1;
  update();
});

update();
document.body.appendChild(cvs);
```

```html
<label>
  Zoom: <input data-slide="zoom" type="range" min="0.5" max="2" value="1" step="0.1">
</label>
<br>
<label>
  Horizontal pan: <input data-slide="panx" value="0" type="range" min="-128" max="128" step="1">
</label>
<br>
<label>
  Vertical pan: <input data-slide="pany" value="0" type="range" min="-128" max="128" step="1">
</label>
<br>


<canvas width="256" height="256" style="border: 1px solid red; background: grey"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this nice snippet. Can you please update the variable names to better reflect what they are. For example what exactly is `t.e`, `t.f` etc. This is a very good example and I will accept your answer soon.

Comment: If you're gonna request the DOMMatrix, why aren't you using it? `const t = ctx.getTransform().invertSelf(); const pt = t.transformPoint({ x, y }); const cx = Math.floor(pt.x / S); const cy = Math.floor(pt.y / S);` -> Handles all transforms.

Comment: @Kaiido, thanks for bringing that up! The reason I manually did the  transform: I wasn't able to find the documentation about these methods in [the place I was looking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrix). Turns out `transformPoint` is in [DOMMatrixReadOnly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMMatrixReadOnly)...